# Can Laravel Spark do this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-spark

If I'm not mistaken, this is a framework that jumpstarts my web app with basic needs?

I have an app that will eventually turn enterprise level granted we deliver in a timely manner and the existing version is a complete mess of code, so we've already agreed to write the minimum viable product (MVP) in Laravel as we need to move fast. The MVP will be very simple, user management of course, the way I see it is basically 3 team groups ... Order placers, Order fulfillment and administrative. Order placers will have 3 levels of completing orders, but basically we need someone with proper credentials to sign off on the order before it is sent to the fulfillment side. And of course the admin side to manage the other two team groups and run reports about billing and what not.

So my question boiled down is this. Can I use Spark in order to build my shopping cart app? Or am I better off creating this just completely in Laravel alone?

Comment: like you said spark=laravel=php anything you can do with php you can do with laravel which you can do in spark

Comment: Spark or no Spark, you'll still have a bunch of work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Spark creates a ton of stuff for you to handle billing, sending users notifications, and whatnot. However, given that it sounds like you need 3 different roles which I'm not sure would be very easy to integrate with Spark.

If you need to manage teams at all then it might be worth giving Spark a go...